# Mingw32 strange linker warning

Tags: linker, mingw, createthread

This is the warning:

```
Warning: resolving _worker by linking to _worker@4
Use --enable-stdcall-fixup to disable these warnings
Use --disable-stdcall-fixup to disable these fixup
```

The function `worker` is the start routine for the CreateThread. This is how is defined:

```
DWORD WINAPI worker (LPVOID args);
```

It is defined in `worker.h`, which I include in `wgroup.c`, where I call the CreateThread.
And this is the call to CreateThread, nothing special:

```
CreateThread (NULL, 0, worker, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

When I run the program, it shut down at (I suspect) the CreateThread call.
The program is being run on Linux under Wine, and this is source of problems with the debug, I've not been able to gather much informations on the crash.

So I think the problem is with that warning. I don't think I should ignore it, and neither I know how to fix it, or what is the linker problem.

Thanks.